# How to handle KeyBoard input messages on non-windowed objects?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-events, delphi-xe3, windows-messages

I read [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/receive-windows-messages-in-custom-delphi-class-nonwindowed-control.htm) about how to create a Window Handle into a non-windowed conrol. I did just the way I read, but nothing happens. So I come to you guys.

My class is this way right now:

```
interface  

type

    TMyObject = class
    private
        fMsgHandlerHWND : HWND;
        procedure WndMethod(var Msg: TMessage);
    public
        constructor Create;
        destructor Destroy; Override;
    end;

implementation

constructor TMyObject.Create;
begin
    inherited;
    fMsgHandlerHWND := AllocateHWnd(WndMethod);
end;

destructor TMyObject.Destroy;
begin
   deallocatehwnd(fMsgHandlerHWND);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyObject.WndMethod(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
    if Msg.Msg = WM_KEYUP then
        MessageBeep(0)
    else
        Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(fMsgHandlerHWND, Msg.Msg, Msg.wParam, Msg.lParam);
end;
```

I do use my `FormCreate` to execute `var := TMyObject.Create`.

Following the line where Windows sends broadcast messages when I press/release a key (correct me if I'm wrong); I'm not sure why it did not work. Somoeone can tell me what did I do wrong? There is another way to catch KeyBoard input with a non-windowed object? If so, how?

Comment: Basically they are posted to the active window, not your hidden window. Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Keyboard_Focus_and_Activation

Comment: @David On the page I showed up there it says `DefWindowProc` is for every other messages (wich I would not process). I have to call it?

Comment: Yes you need to let the system process the messages that relate to creation and destruction

Comment: Should I update the question?

Comment: Well, then I could remove part of my answer and make it cleaner. Btw, convention dictates that type are prefixed with T.

Comment: Updating so... But don't clean your answer yet. See if I'll do right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard events are delivered to the window with input focus. That's never going to be your hidden window.

if you want to catch input events the cleanest way is to use the `OnMessage` event of the global `Application` object. All queued messages pass through this event handler. Subscribe to it using a `TApplicationEvents` instance.

Comment: I think I got. I could not assign a `procedure TForm1.OnMessage(Msg: TagMSG; Handled: Boolean)` to `ApplicationEvents1.OnMessage` under "Parameter lists differ" compile message.

Comment: Handled is a var parameter. Easier to let the designer do all this.  Drop the app events object onto form, find OnMessage in object inspector, double click it.

Comment: Here I come with  my restrictions. If not impossible, I would like to create `TApplicationEvents` instance in runtime. Make `Handled` a var parameter did not solve anyway...

Comment: That's possible. No trouble at all. It does mean you have to get the method signatures right and not rely on the designer.

Comment: Well, I did as Delphi shows the parameters by passing the mouse over the Method's name. I could not follow `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` to a root, by Ctrl + clicking. So where can I find its signature?

Comment: Example here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/TAppEventsOnMessage_(Delphi)

Comment: Dig the signature out of the source code in Vcl.AppEvnts. a bit of an art form.

Comment: I did paste this signature. Still not compiling.

Comment: Keep trying. You'll work it out. Cannot debug it blind from here.

Comment: `TMessageEvent = procedure (var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean) of object` the deepest root for this `OnMessage`. Should be working...

Comment: It was the deal. I just forgot to change the interface as well. Worked very well. Thank you!